# Block a Specific Program from being installed in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, blocking

Is there any way I can block only a specific program/installer (e.g Bluestacks) from being installed in my Windows 10 computer? I want myself to be not able to unblock the software.

Comment: Look into Software Restriction Policy and blocking a specific program that way. You can also set this for yourself too with Group Policy. You can lock this down at BOTH the computer level and the user level BOTH. Give it a try. Another way would be to routinely check for some file exe and then run the uninstall from the registry key with msiexec to silently uninstall if it it installed, some exe in a specific path exists, etc. May be ways to trigger based on Events too. It depends on how elaborate and enforced you are trying to get. AV/security software also has ways to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry this isn't possible. You cannot prevent yourself from doing anything on your computer.

The fact that you can disable something also means you can enable it, and that means you cannot do what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

From what I know of Win 10, you can only disable Installer for a user but not per app.

But you may still check options in 
Computer Configurations > Administrative templates > Windows Components > Windows Installer
of Group Policy editor just in case.

There may be a way to hijack Installer before it's run over registry but it would need some custom code for check and return to the installer but I am not sure of this.

Comment: The same way registry is modified it can be reverted too.

Comment: True, I did not suggest this as resolution only as a possibility. My bad.